# php simple swich case calculator function is not displaying results

Tags: php

I am trying to create a simple php calculator with swich case statement. I used bootstrap buttons to each +,-,*,/ functions. At the end when user fill the form and press any of these buttons it is supposed to display the results in a disabled text field. But it won't display the results

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SIMPLE CALCULATOR</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid mainbox row">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Calculator</h2>
    <div class="container-fluid calbox col-md-4 offset-md-4">
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label style="padding-top: 10px;">Value 1</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Value 1" name="val1" id="val1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Value 2</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Value 2" name="val2" id="val2">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row" style="padding-left: 10px;">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="btn" value="add">+</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="btn" value="sub">-</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="btn" value="mul">*</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="btn" value="div">/</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Result</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="res" value="<?php cal() ?>" disabled>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>

        <?php
        function cal(){
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $val1 = $_POST['val1'];
                $val2 = $_POST['val2'];

                $func = $_POST['btn'];

                switch ($func) {
                    case "add":
                    $compute = $val1 + $val2;
                    break;

                    case "sub":
                    $compute = $val1 - $val2;
                    break;

                    case "mul":
                    $compute = $val1 * $val2;
                    break;

                    case "div":
                    $compute = $val1 / $val2;
                    break;

                    default:
                    $compute = "error";
                    break;
                }
                return $compute;
            }
        }
    ?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery311.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Give some tips to determine the problem

Comment: you cannot call a php function from a html element: `value="<?php cal() ?>"`.

Comment: you should do smth like `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { echo cal(); }`

Comment: You have to defined the function _before_ you call it, better even in a separate file which you include. Then you need to `echo` the functions output.

Comment: @Jeff I tried to call the function outside the html also but it didn't worked

Comment: You can call the function inside the html markup, no issue with that, but you forgot to output anything. Compare these two: `value="<?php cal() ?>"` => `value="<?php echo cal() ?>"`... (or the short tag version `<?= cal() ?>`)

Comment: @arkascha I also tried that but still not working

Comment: And "not working" means what exactly? What _do_ you get and what do you see in your http servers error log file?

Comment: @Kasun : first please comment the `value="<?php cal(); ?>` and replace buttons with input type as i suggested. after that you will get the val1 and val2 and also type. so create your function under `isset($_POST['submit'])` and out your result textbox outside  the form

Comment: Ah, and another obvious issue: Instead of `isset($_POST['submit'])` use `isset($_POST['btn'])`... Using those two modifications your code works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get your code to work by doing these two modifications:

- `<?php cal() ?>` to `<?php echo cal(); ?>`
  Without this you may compute some result, but you never actually output it.
- `isset($_POST['submit'])` to `isset($_POST['btn'])`
  Without that you never compute a result. You do not define an input element with name "submit", but you do define one with the name "btn".

---

Apart from that two general remarks:

- you should move that calculation function to a separate file and include it at the beginning of your file. That keeps separate things separate, logic and presentation.
- you should consider doing such computations *on the client side*, that saves you from doing a full page reload for each calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Check for `$_POST['btn']` instead of `$_POST['submit']`

`var_dump($_POST)` was included for clarity so you can see what is going on.

Also, you want to use `echo` with `cal()` to actually display the result: `value="<?php echo cal()?>"`

I added the entered values to the `val1` and `val2` fields after pressing a button so they appear with the result. This isn't necessary, but for clarity, it helps to see the values used in the calculation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SIMPLE CALCULATOR</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
$val1 = "";
$val2 = "";
if (isset($_POST['btn'])) {
    $val1 = $_POST['val1'];
    $val2 = $_POST['val2'];
}
?>

<div class="container-fluid mainbox row">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Calculator</h2>
    <div class="container-fluid calbox col-md-4 offset-md-4">
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label style="padding-top: 10px;">Value 1</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Value 1" name="val1" id="val1" value="<?php echo $val1 ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Value 2</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Value 2" name="val2" id="val2" value="<?php echo $val2 ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row" style="padding-left: 10px;">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="btn" value="add">+</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="btn" value="sub">-</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="btn" value="mul">*</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="btn" value="div">/</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Result</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="res" value="<?php echo cal()?>" disabled>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>

        <?php
        function cal(){
        $compute = "";
            if (isset($_POST['btn'])) {
                $val1 = $_POST['val1'];
                $val2 = $_POST['val2'];

                $func = $_POST['btn'];

                switch ($func) {
                    case "add":
                    $compute = $val1 + $val2;
                    break;

                    case "sub":
                    $compute = $val1 - $val2;
                    break;

                    case "mul":
                    $compute = $val1 * $val2;
                    break;

                    case "div":
                    $compute = $val1 / $val2;
                    break;

                    default:
                    $compute = "error";
                    break;
                }
            }
        return $compute;
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: As already said in the comments above: you it perfectly fine to call the `cal()` function from within the short tags inside the html input definition. No need to pull it out and place it _before_ the result of the code. That only makes things more complex.

Comment: @arkascha Agreed that it isn't necessary. It is a matter of preference and as the calculator grows in complexity, there may be other things that are done with the result (e.g. history). Doing it up front will allow more flexibility.

Comment: Sorry, but the whole task obviously is a beginners learning task. If this really should grow in complexity then it has to be split into separate files. The way you try to separate it only adds complexity and makes things harder to read.

Comment: @arkascha - Fair criticism. I will modify my answer.

Comment: And btw: that function is called `cal()`, not `calc()`.

Comment: _And_ one should _never_ output debugging stuff inline like this. It typically breaks the GUI and confuses. That is what log files are for.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SIMPLE CALCULATOR</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid mainbox row">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Calculator</h2>
    <div class="container-fluid calbox col-md-4 offset-md-4">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label style="padding-top: 10px;">Value 1</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Value 1" name="val1" id="val1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Value 2</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Value 2" name="val2" id="val2">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row" style="padding-left: 10px;">

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add"  />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="sub"  />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="mul"  />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="div"  />
        </div>

    </form>


    </div>
</div>

        <?php
        function cal($val1,$val2,$func){
           switch ($func) {
                    case "add":
                    $compute = $val1 + $val2;
                    break;

                    case "sub":
                    $compute = $val1 - $val2;
                    break;

                    case "mul":
                    $compute = $val1 * $val2;
                    break;

                    case "div":
                    $compute = $val1 / $val2;
                    break;

                    default:
                    $compute = "error";
                    break;
                }
                return $compute;

        }
        // function cal(){
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
              // print_r($_POST); die;
                $val1 = $_POST['val1'];
                $val2 = $_POST['val2'];
                $method = $_POST['submit'];
                echo $result = cal($val1,$val2,$method);

            }
        // }
    ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot make any sense out of this. The two versions are roughly identical. Both define a value "`add`" for the element, both work as a submit element to the form. The difference is the first is html version and defines a real button, the second is the xhtml version and defines an input element of _type_ submit. But both work like wise. So this does _not_ answer the question.